# How to use Option.flatten with None?

Tags: f#, flatten

There is an error when applying the flatten function on the Option module:

```
let flatten  =
function
| None          -> None
| Some innerOpt -> innerOpt
```

This only works with imputs like: Some Some 1. 
But if the input is "None" then I get this error:

```
flatten None 

error FS0030: Value restriction. The value 'it' has been inferred to have generic type
    val it : '_a option
Either define 'it' as a simple data term, make it a function with explicit arguments or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.
```

How is flatten supposed to work with generics in the None case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`flatten` is a generic function with type `'a option option -> 'a option`. The compiler cannot infer the type parameter to use for the automatic REPL variable `it` (which is the result of the previous expression) when the argument is `None`. You can specify your own variable:

```
let it : int option = flatten None;;
```

explicitly specify the type of `None`:

```
flatten (None : int option option);;
```

or

```
flatten (Option<int option>.None);;
```

or specify the generic parameter explicitly to `flatten`:

```
flatten<int> None;;
```

this generates a warning which you can remove by making the type parameter to `flatten` explicit:

```
let flatten<'a> (o : 'a option option) =
    match o with
    | None          -> None
    | Some innerOpt -> innerOpt
```

Comment: `flattenOption (None : int option option)` is another way to specify the type of the argument explicitly. Check out https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mulambda/2010/05/01/finer-points-of-f-value-restriction/ for more details.

Comment: But shouldn't it work without specifying it to be generic. In the case of Option.flatten for example, I cannot change the implementation. So I would get the same error, unless I specify the type for the variable as in : let result : int option . Why does this implementation doesn't work with None. I understand that it is because it is supposed to be generic ,but doesn't this mean that the implementation is wrong? Shouldn't it work with None, without modifying anything?. I mean, if it works with Some, it should work with None, without the need of any modification.

Comment: @FraK - Your definition of `flatten` is generic, the problem is with inferring the generic type parameter when providing `None` as an argument. There are three ways of providing the type in the answer that don't require you to redefine `flatten`. The return value `None` cannot have a polymorphic type in F# so you need to specify it either in the type of the argument or the type of the result.

Comment: @Lee But then what about `Option<int>.None`?

Comment: So many good options(no pun intended). Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Old question/answer, I know, but I would express the function as follows to avoid type annotations: ``let flatten = function | Some ((Some _) as inner) -> inner | _ -> None`` — However, this would still need a type annotation when evaluating ``flatten None`` unless there is preceding context to provide the type.